# Creating a default launcher app for Android Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a default launcher app for an Android TV box that used to work until I ran into some unexpected issues and had to reset the TV Box to factory default. Now it doesn't work anymore. I used to get a "Select Default Launcher" popup when pressing back from my app, but not anymore.

My Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="gensys.firefly.fireflyhikviewer">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FireflyHikViewer">

        <receiver
            android:name=".Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/banner"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/icon2"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!--<uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

I also updated my Android Studio to 4.2.1, so I don't know if that might have changed something.

Please help.

Comment: Let's see the entire manifest

Comment: I updated my post with the entire manifest. Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, I just made the app boot after the tv box has booted completely.